# Replace `0` with `N/A` or `-1` in pivot query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have Attendance table in which date and attendance is stored and I am passing date range in this query to display attendance report.

Now my question is how can I replace 0 (which I am getting as a output if the date passsed doesn't match with the date inside the Attendance table) with N/A or -1 ?

```
SET @query = 'SELECT RollNo,FirstName,LastName, ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select S.RollNo,U.FirstName,U.LastName,
            D.startdate,
            convert(CHAR(10), startdate, 120) PivotDate
            from #tempDates D,Attendance A, Student S, UserDetails U
            where D.startdate = A.Date and A.EnrollmentNo=S.EnrollmentNo and A.EnrollmentNo=U.userID
        ) x
       pivot 
       (
            count(startdate)
            for PivotDate in (' + @cols + ')
       ) p '
```

Comment: Can you please fix your tags so that the  readers know which database server you use?

Comment: What's wrong with 0? I would keep the date inside the database as 0 and with whatever program that is using this data, parse it to 'N/A'. Much easier and more efficient than doing conversions on the DB directly. Also, depending on the language you're using to consume your data, you may get exceptions if you do it that way since you never really know if that column is going to be an int or a string.

Comment: My Bad , fixed!

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  It's either MySQL or SQL Server, can't be both.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Good point but I need to differentiate between a student present in the class and the holiday, in both cases, attendance is 0.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?

Comment: Can you use CASE? Example: `CASE When PivotDate = 0 THEN -1 END as PDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CASE as Brandon Miller suggested. Here's another option - you can use NULLIF to replace a zero with a null value, and then replace any null value with N/A. You'll need to create a 2nd variable to represent your columns in the select statement of your dynamic query. Here's a full example with test data:

```
-- test data
create table #tempDates (startdate date)
create table Attendance (date date, enrollmentno int)
create table Student (rollno int, enrollmentno int)
create table UserDetails (FirstName varchar(10), LastName varchar(10), userid int)

insert into #tempDates values ('1/1/2018')
insert into Attendance values ('1/1/2018', 1)
insert into Student values (1, 1)
insert into UserDetails values ('J', 'S', 1)

declare @cols varchar(100) = '[2018-01-01],[2018-01-02]'
declare @cols_select varchar(500) = 'ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST([2018-01-01] AS VARCHAR(10)), ''0''), ''N/A'') AS [2018-01-01],ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST([2018-01-02] AS VARCHAR(10)), ''0''), ''N/A'') AS [2018-01-02]'

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
SET @query = 'SELECT RollNo,FirstName,LastName, ' 
    + @cols_select
    + 'from 
     (
        select S.RollNo,U.FirstName,U.LastName,
        D.startdate,
        convert(CHAR(10), startdate, 120) PivotDate
        from #tempDates D,Attendance A, Student S, UserDetails U
        where D.startdate = A.Date and A.EnrollmentNo=S.EnrollmentNo and A.EnrollmentNo=U.userID
    ) x
   pivot 
   (
        count(startdate)
        for PivotDate in (' + @cols + ')
   ) p '

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Outputs:

```
RollNo  FirstName   LastName    2018-01-01  2018-01-02
1       J           S           1           N/A
```

For fun, here's a function you can use to convert the @cols variable to the @cols_select variable:

```
create function dbo.fn_convert_cols(@cols varchar(max)) returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @col varchar(20)
    declare @cols_select varchar(max) = ''

    declare @idx int, @idx2 int
    select @idx = CHARINDEX('[', @cols), @idx2 = CHARINDEX(']', @cols)
    while @idx > 0 and @idx2 > 0
    begin
        select @col = SUBSTRING(@cols, @idx + 1, @idx2 - @idx - 1)
        select @cols_select += ',ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST([' + @col + '] AS VARCHAR(10)), ''0''), ''N/A'') AS [' + @col + ']' 
        select @cols = SUBSTRING(@cols, @idx2 + 1, len(@cols) - @idx2)
        select @idx = CHARINDEX('[', @cols), @idx2 = CHARINDEX(']', @cols)
    end

    select @cols_select = SUBSTRING(@cols_select, 2, len(@cols_select) - 1) 
    return @cols_select
end
go
```

So now you can just call the function when you're building the query, like this:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT RollNo,FirstName,LastName, ' + dbo.fn_convert_cols(@cols)+ ' from
```

Comment: I cannot yet. It says wait for 2 days before you can accept an answer as I'm a beginner here and don't have much reputations.

Comment: One problem that I just saw with the current solution is that it's converting "0" attendance, which represents the absence, to N/A also.